# List all the subgroups of C12 and compute the index of each

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Ok, so I’m slowly progressing with my Abstract course. Ill post my work first and then point out my confusion or doubt, I suppose.

I’m fairly certain that there are six subgroups. The trivial subgroup (just the identity), the improper subgroup (all of G), and subgroups of order 2,3,4, and 6.

I gathered this from the factors of 12. I went ahead and computed the gcd(12,s) where s runs from 1 to 12 to obtain the above orders. There were duplicates. For example x3=x9=order3.

The generators of the group are x1, x5, x7, x11. This is gained from the coprimes from 1 to 12 with 12. All the generators have order 12

I guess my question is when subgroups of duplicate order are found, do we just treat them as the same subgroup. They are the same subgroup, right? So we aren’t concerned with which element of G is necessarily involved, but rather just the subgroup that is produced by the given order?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Two subgroups with exactly the same elements are in fact the same subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

Two subgroups are equal if and only if they have the exact same set of elements. Just having the same order is not enough! It happens to be true that two subgroups of $C_{12}$ are equal if and only if they have the same order, but that will not be the case in general. For example, $C_2 \times C_2$ has three distinct subgroups of order $2$ (can you find them?)

To answer your question: yes, your classification of the subgroups of $C_{12}$ is correct.